# AJAX Database connectivity not established

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, database

I'm trying to login by providing email, password and tag.

The problem is that success inside `.$ajax` is not called.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.shake.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#login').click(function()
            {
                var username=$("#username").val();
                var password=$("#password").val();
                var dataString = 'email='+username+'&password='+password+'&tag=login';

                if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
                {


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://192.168.0.110/XXX/index.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Connecting...');},
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data)
                            {
                                alert('TRUE');
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                alert('FALSE');
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                return false;
            });


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Ajax Login Page with Shake Effect</h1>

        <div id="box">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Username</label> 
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="username"/>
                <label>Password </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="password"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Log In" id="login"/> 
                <span class='msg'></span> 

                <div id="error">

                </div>  

            </form> 
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the alert functions are not called. I got connecting only. The PHP file is correct, I tried it from an android application.

Comment: So you are not seeing an alert of true or false?

Comment: No I'm not. As far as is know, one alert should be called at least. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try an alert outside your ajax call.

Comment: The alert works outside  the AJAX call.

Comment: Do you see the request in the network tab of developer tools? Is there a response? I would try echoing `$_POST` in your PHP script to see if the values were received. I suspect your query string is not being built properly.